# Automate Class sessions

Tags: javascript, html, c++, ubuntu, web-scraping

I was trying to automate my classes so that whenever I run my command in ubuntu it launches the session.
I was able to lauch the window upto the subject but the issue I am facing is,I can't get an exact link for blackboard session as it keeps changing for every sesson.
And when I tried to copy the link address it copied "javascript:void(0);".
I written this code in c++.
Can someone guide me through this?

Comment: Without seeing the code and having access to the website you're trying to automate, noone can help you. I suggest you investigate tools like webdriver and puppet to "drive" an existing browser and click links in a pattern you describe programatically.

Comment: Output when I inspects it."<a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitem" ng-click="courseOutline.joinSession(courseOutline.courseRoomSession.id)" analytics-id="course.outline.collab.sessionList.courseRoom.link"> <span bb-translate="course.outline.collab.ultraCollabMenu.courseRoom" course-org-token-resolver="">Course Room</span> </a>"

Comment: Yes, you will need to drive an actual browser to do that. Look into webdriver or browser automation technology.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.